# Adding class to all childrens(in first level o hierarchy) of specified element in javascript without jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, addclass, children

I want to change this from jquery to javascript:
`$('#id_of_element').children('div').addClass('some_class');`

So far all i have is this(not working):
`document.getElementById('id_of_element').getElementsByTagName('div').addClass('some_class');`

I have to change all my code from jquery to javascript. Is there any site with have examples of functions in javascript next to jquery? Thanks in advance for all help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
var el = document.getElementById('elem'),
    //modern browsers IE >= 10
    classList = 'classList' in el;
for (var i = 0; i < el.children.length; i++) {
    var child = el.children[i];
    if (child.tagName == 'DIV') {
        if (classList) {
            child.classList.add('test');
        } else {
            child.className += ' test'
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NN5Jr/)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone wants to loop through all children, this worked for me:

```js
const addClassList = (element) => {
  Object.values(element.children).forEach((e) => {
    e.classList.add('myClass');
    if (e.children.length > 0) addClassList(e);
  });
};

addClassList(myElement);
```

NOTE:
Does not work with conditional rendering

Answer (score -1):

Remove the hash(#): in javascript you don't need to use `#` when selecting id.

```
document.getElementById('id_of_element').getElementsByTagName('div').addClass('some_class');
```